# favorite links with jqueryui sortable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to make a 'favorite links page' where the sitemap is on the left, and you can drag your preferred links to the right.  The items on the left that have been added to the list on the right are disabled, if the items on the right are drug back, their corresponding item on the left is enabled.  I'm thinking I can use this: *jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists* and this: *jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#items* but I haven't found any options that seem to fit this use case.  Would I be better off just making something custom using droppable items (like this *jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#shopping-cart*)?  I'm just looking for some info here, because I don't want to head down a dead end.  Thanks,

nu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable